# Adding together timedeltas in Python

Tags: python, list, datetime, timedelta

So I have this list:

```
[datetime.timedelta(0, 1800), datetime.timedelta(0, 1800), datetime.timedelta(0, 1800), datetime.timedelta(0, 1800)]
```

Collectively that is 2:00 hours. I'm trying to add those up to get 2:00 time delta, which then in turn needs to be turned into a string of 2.0 Hours. Respectively 1:30 Hours would be 1.5 Hours as the final countdown.

Comment: `import operator;reduce(operator.add, YourList)`

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed ... lol SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naive approach would be to take the `seconds` from each object and `sum` them

```
>>> a = [datetime.timedelta(0, 1800)] * 4
>>> print sum([d.seconds for d in a])
7200
>>> print sum([d.seconds for d in a]) / 60.0 / 60.0
2.0
```

but this is not as robust as Haidro's solution:

```
import operator
reduce(operator.add, a)
```

This results in a `timedelta` object with the correct delta that you can use however you want.

Comment: Summing `.seconds` is risky. You'll drop hours and microseconds so it's a pretty big assumption not to include them. Either use `.total_seconds()` (python 2.7) or do the math to include hours/microseconds.

Comment: Hah! Operator is amazing, you're right better off going that route. By chance how can you remember all these different module so effectively?

Comment: @Matthew Heh, well, the operator solution was mine, so I guess I'll answer this. Overtime when answering questions I learn a lot of things, such as built-in functions I've never seen before or awesome modules, such as this one. The `operator` special is nothing special, it's just a simplified version of something else. For example, `operator.add(a, b)` is the same as `a + b`.

Comment: Either version is overkill. You don't have to call `sum` on the `d.total_seconds()` values, when you can just call it directly on the values. And you don't have to build `sum` manually out of `reduce` when you can just use the builtin.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious way to sum anything number-like and addable in Python is with the [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
>>> dts = [datetime.timedelta(0, 1800), datetime.timedelta(0, 1800), datetime.timedelta(0, 1800), datetime.timedelta(0, 1800)]
>>> sum(dts, start=datetime.timedelta(0))
datetime.timedelta(0, 9, 933279)
```

(For most number-like types, you don't even need the `start` value, because they know how to add themselves to `0`. `timedelta` explicitly does not allow this, to avoid accidentally mixing dimensionless intervals—e.g., you don't want to add `timeout_in_millis` to a `timedelta`…)

---

Whenever you're using `reduce` with `operator.add` for number-like values, you're probably doing it wrong.

If you don't provide an `initial` argument to `reduce`, it will do the wrong thing with an empty list, raising a `TypeError` instead of returning the `0` value. (The sum of no numbers is 0; the sum of no `timedelta`s is `timedelta(0)`; etc.)

And if you do provide an `initial` argument, then it's just a more verbose, more complicated, and slower way to write `sum`. Compare:

```
functools.reduce(operator.add, a, foo(0))
sum(a, foo(0))
```